# Would get back to me but never did?

Tags: human-resources

**Edit**: I have managed to get their phone number and haven't given them a call.  However, on their answer machine, the manager has an email address/phone number to their PA.  Would it be a good opportunity to get in touch with his/her PA and ask stating 'I completely understand that person X is busy'.

I recently was in contact with a technology company about a work experience placement.  This required a background check for full time employees, however since I was only going to be there 'part time', the manager stated that she would get back to me shortly in regards to this background check as it will be assessed on a case-by-case basis.

The manager stated that she would get back to me 'shortly', it has been a month and I completely understand that she is busy, however I was wondering what the best way to word this would be.  I was thinking along the lines of the following:

> Dear Ms. Johnson, 
>   
>   I am writing this in regards to the email you sent me on the XX.  Is there anything I can do in order to assist you in expediting the process?

However, this sounds really pushy, and I wouldn't be too happy to receive an email like that if I was the hiring manager, would anyone be able to give me any ideas?

Thanks!

Comment: That does not sound pushy at all.,

Comment: @MaskedMan No this is different.  believed me I checked.

Comment: If anything you should put the edited information at the bottom of the post. Also, about the edit, I think you should contact the original person if possible, waiting a reasonable time for a response. Don't go around them to someone else unless really necessary (doing so may seem pushy).

Comment: @Brandin He's really really busy, I understand that considering he's like a regional manager and has so much stuff to do, however since he said in the email that 'we'd be happy to explore a work experience'.  I left him a message three days ago but he hasn't responded likely cause he is busy... how do you think I can proceed?  Contact his PA?  Because he did say that he is happy to explore a work experience.... and I really love this company too :)

Comment: You should leave a message first for the original person, even if busy. And wait for a response. Contacting someone else about it might be seen as an "escalation".

Answer (score 1):

Don't make them lookup the email sent on xxx
Reply to that email
And put a delivery receipt on it so you know they got it

> Sorry to bother you but do you have a status on the background check?

Comment: I'd say don't put a delivery receipt on it.
1) They can be ignored and not sent to you anyway
2) They really upset some people who get dozens of them a day

Answer (score 0):

I would say that your response is blunt and offers something you likely cannot provide - help in expediting.  For that reason, I would pursue a different strategy.

I suggest you consider the following:

**Dear John**:  Is their lack of action a hidden 'Dear John' letter?  Are they just not calling you back because they are no longer interested?

**Busy**:  Is there operation so busy that they cannot deal with this right now?  Did some other *fire* start burning that is more important than hiring?

Often when faced with a touchy decision, I consider:

- What is the best that could happen?
- What is the worst that could happen?
- Am I willing to accept the worst or the best?

If I don't care about the consequences, I'd write something like you've already written.  However, I tend to write *classic business letters* even when writing email.  I try to:

1. Remind them about me and the last items we discussed
2. Tell them the status so they are informed.  They might be surprised that nothing happened.
3. Tell them what I will do or what I want them to do.
4. Give them a way out of an awkward situation.  Give them an opportunity to say 'no thank you'.

*Dear ..., I'm looking forward to the opportunity to work for ... Last we spoke, you indicated that a background check may or may not be needed.  I have neither received an offer nor have I heard about the potential background check.  Are you still interested in having me work for ...?  If so, what is the next step in the process?  Regards, ...*

If you want to be pushy and force their hand, call them on the phone.  Don't bother sending an email.  Call your point of contact (preferably the person you'd be working for) and ask if the position is still open and about the next steps.  It is rarely HR that has an incentive to fill positions, it is the manager you'll be working under.  Go straight to that person.

Comment: "I have neither received an offer nor have I heard about the potential background check." - they should already know this, and you saying it may come across as pushy or impatient already.

Comment: They did not speak.  It was an email.

Comment: The person asking for 'work experience' is asking and not in a position to demand.  It doesn't matter what they should know.  It has been a 'month' and either M. Anderson has been forgotten, the company is too busy, or they don't want him.  Honey attracts more than vinegar.  Do your best to be patient, kind, and courteous and you'll get more than if you demand or try to make somebody feel guilty.

Answer (score -1):

Perfectly reasonable e-mail. It is possible they simply forgot to respond, or that their idea of"shortly" is a rather long one.

Or they may not have bothered telling you that they didn't have a place for you.

Comment: thank you!  They did mention that 'We would be happy to explore a work experience opportunity for you within our operation'... Is there any way you think I can extend that email I wrote above, maybe make it sound more polite?  Thanks!